# Binary search in a list which contains 2 sorted sections

Tags: python, binary-search

I know that binary search only works in a sorted list.

I want to search ( O(log n) ) and be able to find an item in a list with 2 sorted sections.

EX: [20,30,1,2,3,4,5]

Is O(log n) binary search the only option?

I want to split the list where the order is lost, however, as the list size changes it would no longer be at the complexity I want it?

Comment: I think you would use binary search to find the split `O(log(n))`, then you could do binary search on each half `O(log(n))*2` =>`O(3log(n)) => O(log(n))` ... i think at least

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches for this particular problem, which will give you O(log n) solution -

1. As @joran mentioned, you can first search for the split point in the list in O(log n), and do binary search again on both the lists, resulting in an overall complexity of O(log n).
2. You can search for the element in the list in a single pass of binary search with a minor variation in logic. As mentioned in the below code -

   ```
   # Search an element in sorted and rotated array using
   # single pass of Binary Search

   # Returns index of key in arr[l..h] if key is present,
   # otherwise returns -1
   def search(arr, l, h, key):
       if l > h:
           return -1

       mid = (l + h) // 2
       if arr[mid] == key:
           return mid

       # If arr[l...mid] is sorted
       if arr[l] <= arr[mid]:

           # As this subarray is sorted, we can quickly
           # check if key lies in half or other half
           if key >= arr[l] and key <= arr[mid]:
               return search(arr, l, mid - 1, key)
           return search(arr, mid + 1, h, key)

       # If arr[l..mid] is not sorted, then arr[mid... r]
       # must be sorted
       if key >= arr[mid] and key <= arr[h]:
           return search(a, mid + 1, h, key)
       return search(arr, l, mid - 1, key)


   # Driver program
   arr = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3]
   key = 6
   i = search(arr, 0, len(arr) - 1, key)
   if i != -1:
       print ("Index: %d" % i)
   else:
       print ("Key not found")
   ```

To take a look at the code of the first approach as well - have a look at the following post - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/search-an-element-in-a-sorted-and-pivoted-array/